# Vimeo android sdk : Is there any vimeo API like Youtube to play vimeo videos?

Tags: android, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

I have to implement Vimeo video player in my android Application. I have found few solutions like playing video in WebView etc. But this is not a proper way. Need help

Comment: share your code and what you have tried

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54252590/5065348

Answer (score 1):

Vimeo provides API's which are found at:
http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple

Answer (score 1):

> vimeo-networking is a Java networking library used for interacting with the Vimeo API. The example provided in this project shows the implementation in the context of an Android app.

https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java